# Is there any event for Session Time Out in PHP

Tags: php, session, timeout

I'm using a web services and service's results carry a large data, so I save the Xml datas in FTP with a sesssion ID, but I want to do that when session timed out,check the Session's ID and delete Xml file in ftp. Is there anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard PHP sessions, there's no way to track when a particular session expires. the garbage collector has a random chance of being executed during EVERY invocation of a php script, and it will not report what it's doing, or what sessions were pruned.

If you want to track which sessions were expired and do extra cleanup when that happens, you'll have to roll your own session handler: [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)